# How do I calculate percentage by using a particular value as a base?

Tags: mysql

[code_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXdri.png)

I have a dataset containing all countries and their CO2 emissions from 1990 to 2020. The problem is that I want to find the percentage of total Co2 emissions for each country separately by using the 1990 value as the base value for each country to get separate emissions percentages for different countries. however, when I run this query ( which I have attached), I get an error saying, Subquery returns more than 1 row because each country has data starting from 1990.
If someone can guide and help me here, I'll be grateful.

I am doing this project for practice and experience as I just started learning SQL myself.

Comment: you should not post image of code

Comment: You should aggregate the data in the subquery so that it returns a single row instead of multiple rows.